# how to pass double quote as a parameter to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, csv

I am having a repl.bat file which replaces a string1 by another string2. its syntax is like this

**type input.csv |repl "String1" "String2"  >  ouput1.csv**

I want to replace Double Quotes by space and write data into output.csv file

I have tried like this...

```
     type input.csv |repl """ " "  >  ouput1.csv
```

it is throwing an error " The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

What to do??? plz help......

Comment: you need show us the code of `repl.bat`. Maybe escape double quote will fix your problem `repl "\"" " "`

Comment: you can find repl.bat file here  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat"

Comment: Maybe try ... repl ^" " " > output1.csv

Comment: @Mark Setchell Sorry man.. Bad luck.. same error again......

Comment: Can't access your repl.bat file, so it's hard to test!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type input.csv | repl "\x22" " " X >  ouput1.csv
type input.csv | repl "\q"   " " X >  ouput1.csv
```

You need to use the *extended substitution pattern syntax* (`X` switch) and use `\x22` to indicate the double quote character hexadecimal ASCII code, or `\q` to indicate a quote (double quote).

Comment: Superb.........big Thanx man.. but can i know what is this extended substitution pattern syntax

Comment: @alluhur, `repl.bat /?`

Comment: can you edit that "repl.bat" so that i should have only one batch file in my project work. my input file is input.csv and output should be output.csv. (I mean that i dont want to give parameters to repl) if i run repl.bat automatically it should read text from input.bat and produce output.csv by replacing as above). Thanx in advance. Please help.